# How to select "AccountId" based on UserId in AspUsers table in model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to get `AccountId` based on current User Id from `AspUsers` table. I am using `identity` to grab current user id. But no idea how to get `AccountId`. Anyone please suggest me.

```
string UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();          
           ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            string AccountId = context.Users.Where(x=>x.UserName== userName).Select(m => m.AccountID).ToString();
```

But I am not getting `AccountId`. Please help me.

Comment: you need some form of a `Where`.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I have edited the question but still not working.

Comment: define not working.

Comment: I am getting this error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT 
   [Extent1].[AccountID] AS [AccountID]
   FROM [dbo].[AspUsers] AS [Extent1]
   WHERE [Extent1].[UserName] = @p__linq__0' to data type int.

Comment: is `AccountID` an `int`? the db says its a string.

Comment: AccountID is int

Comment: try changing that property to string.

Comment: In database, AccountID is an int. Where shall i change the property to string. And in my code, string AccountId = context.Users.Where(x=>x.UserName== userName).Select(m => m.AccountID).ToString();

Comment: instead of tostring(), try use convert.tostring(the code here)?

Comment: @Se0ng11, I did `string AccountId = Convert.ToString( context.Users.Where(x=>x.UserName== userName).Select(m => m.AccountID));`   but still getiing the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` returns a collection (well, technically a *query* that represents a collection). Use `Single` to get a single value:

```
string AccountId = context.Users
                          .Single(x=>x.UserName == userName)
                          .AccountID
                          .ToString();
```